# How do I cancel emails sending from within "\Swift_Events_SendListener" event in Symfony2?

Tags: email, symfony, events

Following [this guide](http://sgoettschkes.blogspot.nl/2012/09/symfony2-testing-email-sending.html) I've set up an event listener:

```
<?php

class EmailListener implements \Swift_Events_SendListener
{
    public $beforeSendEvt = null;
    public $sendEvt = null;

    public function beforeSendPerformed(\Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
    {
        $this->beforeSendEvt = $evt;
    }

    public function sendPerformed(\Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
    {
        $this->sendEvt = $evt;
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to cancel this email in `beforeSendPerformed` method. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably:

```
$evt->cancelBubble();
```

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/613354e08fbddce0943646932b007be9873c658f/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php#L155-L158
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/613354e08fbddce0943646932b007be9873c658f/lib/classes/Swift/Events/EventObject.php#L44-L62